# Prevent action if input field data is not right. (js)

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

I am stuck here with some issue. There are 3 two entry boxes: for birthday, an amount and an interest rate (%). If you click on the button, the page will show an overview of the balance until the amount have to be doubled.
So the issue is: When I enter an incorrect date, I get a notification. However, the interest is still calculated afterwards. I want to prevent code from being executed with incorrect input.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = loop;
var inputA = document.getElementById("inputA");
var inputB = document.getElementById("inputB");
var inputC = document.getElementById("inputC");
var result = document.getElementById("result")

function allFunctions() {
    correctBirthday()
    sum();
    rate();
    loop();
}

 function loop() {
  var s = inputB.value;
  var r = inputC.value;
  var doubleS = s * 2;
  while (s < doubleS) {
    s = ((r / 100 + 1) * s);
    result.innerHTML += s + "<br>";
  }
  if (inputA.value == '')
    { alert('Please enter a value for input A');
  return;
 }
}

function correctDate(datum) {
    var vorm = /^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;
    return vorm.test(datum);
}

function correctBirthday() {
    var d = inputA.value;
    if ( correctDate(d) == false ) {
        alert("The form of the date is incorrect");
        return;
    }
    if ( validDate(d) ) {
        result.innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function rate() {
    var r = rentepercentage.value;
    if ( correctRate(r) == true ) {
        alert("The form of the amount entered is incorrect");
        return;
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function correctRate(rente) {
    var vorm = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    return vorm.test(rente);
}


function sum() {
    var s = bedrad.value;
    if ( correctSum(s) === true ) {
        alert("The form of the amount entered is incorrect");
        return;
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function correctSum(som) {
    var vorm = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    return vorm.test(som);
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<br>
<input type="text" id="inputA" value="05-06-1986"><br>
<input type="text" id="inputB" value="10"><br>
<input type="text" id="inputC"  value="4"><br><br>


<button id="button">Klik</button>

<p> De ingevoerde resultaten: </p>
<p id="result"></p>

<script async src="oefin1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the issue is: When I enter an incorrect date, I get a notification. However, the interest is still calculated afterwards. I want to prevent code from being executed with incorrect input.

Comment: I haven't looked deeply into the problem yet, but you have re-declared the variable `inputB` at the top: ```var inputB = document.getElementById("inputA");
var inputB = document.getElementById("inputB");```

Comment: Sorry... This is a typo. But the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

In your `allFunctions` function:

```
function allFunctions() {
    correctBirthday()
    sum();
    rate();
    loop();
}
```

If `correctBirthday` returns undefined, `allFunctions` does not know that it should stop. You have two main options:

1. Throw an error if the birthday is incorrect, and catch it later:

```js
function allFunctions() {
    try {
        correctBirthday()
        sum();
        rate();
        loop();
    } catch ( error ) {
        alert( error.message );
    }
}

function correctBirthday() {
    var d = inputA.value;
    if ( correctDate(d) == false ) {
        throw new Error("The form of the date is incorrect");
    }
    if ( validDate(d) ) {
        result.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

2. Let `correctBirthday` return `true` or `false` depending on whether it succeeded, and let `allFunctions` respond appropriately:

```js
function allFunctions() {
    let birthdayIsCorrect = correctBirthday();
    if ( !birthdayIsCorrect ) {
        return;
    )
    sum();
    rate();
    loop();
}

function correctBirthday() {
    var d = inputA.value;
    if ( correctDate(d) == false ) {
        alert("The form of the date is incorrect");
        return false;
    }
    if ( validDate(d) ) {
        result.innerHTML = '';
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT: If you want this behaviour when `validDate(d)` is false as well, try...

```js
function correctBirthday() {
    var d = inputA.value;
    if ( correctDate(d) == false ) {
        throw new Error("The form of the date is incorrect");
    }
    if ( !validDate(d) ) {
        throw new Error("The date is invalid");
    }
    result.innerHTML = '';
}

// or...


function correctBirthday() {
    var d = inputA.value;
    if ( correctDate(d) == false ) {
        alert("The form of the date is incorrect");
        return false;
    }
    if ( !validDate(d) ) {
        alert("The date is invalid");
        return false;
    }
    result.innerHTML = '';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jack! It work only if birthday field is empty... I mean I don't get calculation. But when I enter an incorrect date the interest is still calculated afterwards...

Comment: I presume you'll also want to respond to when `validDate(d)` returns false; you could throw an Error, or return false, if it does so. I didn't suggest this because I wanted to answer your question with as few changes as possible :) See edit to follow...